# Why do I have only one thread id when using Async.Parallel?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#

Why do I have only one processor id when using Async.Parallel?

Code:

```
open System
open System.Threading

[for i in 1..10 -> async {return i}] |> Async.Parallel
                                     |> Async.RunSynchronously
                                     |> Seq.iter (fun i -> printfn "Processor Id: %d Value: %d" Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId i)
```

Output:

> ```
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 1
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 2
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 3
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 4
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 5
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 6
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 7
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 8
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 9
> Processor Id: 1 Value: 10
> ```

```
val it : unit = ()

>
```

Comment: "Managed Thread Id" is not "Processor Id".

Comment: My question was short and simple. Why was a point deducted?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin he's not measuring processor ids. The string is misnamed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing `printfn` from your main thread, outside your async workflow. Try this:

```
[for i in 1..10 -> 
    async {return sprintf "Processor Id: %d Value: %d" Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId i}] 
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```